# SocketRocket not working on iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, websocket, socketrocket

I just made a simple real-time text chat application using SocketRocket.  It works great on iOS 6.0 and 5.1 but when I try to run it on 5.0 when connecting I get the following error...

```
Websocket Failed With Error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-9800 "The
operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9800.)"
UserInfo=0x6e506e0 {}
```

Does anyone have any idea what this could mean or how to fix it?  I browsed the issues on github but couldnt find anything and its claimed to work on iOS5+.

EDIT: To add, this is when I test on simulator.  I dont have a device that has 5.0, so im not sure if fails on the phone in the same way.  Also, if I use ws as opposed to wss (encrypted), it seems to work fine.

Comment: I can test it on an iOS 5 device. Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Ill see If I can post something replicating it tomorrow.  I haven't tested the sample app with SocketRocket to see if it has the same behavior.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but according to [this page](https://github.com/vert-x/vert.x/issues/269), -9800 is an SSL protocol error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved in a recent commit to SocketRocket: https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/issues/77

Answer (score 1):

This error has been reported over problems with iOS's SSL authentication.  One report suggested changing from kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1  to kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3.

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I get home I will test this

Comment: Sadly it didnt seem to work.  Same error for all the different security levels